# How to fill color in particular cell in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have created a data Frame which has a column `Status`.
This column can have two values - `Success` and `Failed`.
I want to fill color to all rows in this column with value `Failed`.

Please help me to implement this?

example:
Sample dataframe is given below:

```
Master Job Name   Status

Settlement_limit  Success
Settlement_Trans  **Failed**
Ix_rm_bridge      Success
Unit_test         **Failed**
```

Comment: @Dennis.M no This link is not my answer.

Comment: You are trying to add colors to the cells in a dataframe right? If not, please explain your question clearly.

Comment: Can you explain what you’re trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use [Styler.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to apply style functions elementwise

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Master Job Name':['Settlement_limit', 'Settlement_Trans', 'Ix_rm_bridge', 'Unit_test'], 
        'Status':['Success', 'Failed', 'Success', 'Failed']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# function to fill font color
def fill_color(val):
    return 'color: red' if val=='Failed' else ''

df = df.style.applymap(fill_color, subset=['Status'])
df.to_excel('mysheet.xlsx') # excel sheet will be saved to present working directory, open the excel sheet to view changes
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i want to fill red color in whole cell then what to do?

Comment: change the return value in the function  to `'background-color: red' if val=='Failed' else ''`

Comment: i am running this code in sublime text. while running its not reflecting the color.

Comment: if you want to view the changes run the code in a jupyter notebook, oterwise save to an excel sheet (updated the code )

Comment: i saved the dataframe in csv file. But red color is still not showing.

Comment: a `csv` is a comma seperated `text` file, you cannot save styles to a `csv`, you have to save to an excel file(extension `.xlsx` or `.xls`), then only you can view styles.

Comment: to save a dataframe to excel with `.xlsx` extension pandas need either `xlsxwriter` or  `openpyxl` library , so check if its available, otherwise install one of those, using `pip install openpyxl` , if you are using anaconda do `conda install -c anaconda openpyxl`

Comment: i saved dataframe in .xlsx extension but still background color is not showing.

Comment: did you save back to df , `df = df.style.applymap(fill_color, subset=['Status'])`? copy paste the above code and see if its working. it should work

Comment: Thanks.. Now its working.